# how to get the data from this json-like file use Windows command line?

Tags: json

I want to capture the total_hashrate data from this json(-like?) file in Windows:

```
{
  "miner": {
    "devices": [
      {
        "accepted_shares": 326,
        "core_clock": 1299,
        "core_utilization": 100,
        "fan": 85,
        "hashrate": "53.98 M",
        "hashrate2": "0.000 ",
        "hashrate2_raw": 0,
        "hashrate_raw": 53977101.17434701,
        "id": 0,
        "info": "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Ti",
        "invalid_shares": 0,
        "mem_clock": 10541,
        "mem_utilization": 100,
        "pci_bus_id": 3,
        "power": 179,
        "rejected_shares": 1,
        "temperature": 62
      },
      {
        "accepted_shares": 445,
        "core_clock": 1029,
        "core_utilization": 99,
        "fan": 95,
        "hashrate": "78.68 M",
        "hashrate2": "0.000 ",
        "hashrate2_raw": 0,
        "hashrate_raw": 78678367.75194064,
        "id": 1,
        "info": "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 Ti",
        "invalid_shares": 0,
        "mem_clock": 10541,
        "mem_utilization": 100,
        "pci_bus_id": 7,
        "power": 272,
        "rejected_shares": 2,
        "temperature": 63
      },
      {
        "accepted_shares": 229,
        "core_clock": 1166,
        "core_utilization": 100,
        "fan": 85,
        "hashrate": "42.82 M",
        "hashrate2": "0.000 ",
        "hashrate2_raw": 0,
        "hashrate_raw": 42818658.5005993,
        "id": 2,
        "info": "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070",
        "invalid_shares": 0,
        "mem_clock": 7693,
        "mem_utilization": 89,
        "pci_bus_id": 11,
        "power": 124,
        "rejected_shares": 1,
        "temperature": 59
      }
    ],
    "total_hashrate": "175.5 M",
    "total_hashrate2": "0.000 ",
    "total_hashrate2_raw": 0,
    "total_hashrate_raw": 175474127.42688695,
    "total_power_consume": 575
  },
  "reboot_times": 0,
  "start_time": 1629840480,
  "stratum": {
    "accepted_shares": 1000,
    "algorithm": "ethash",
    "difficulty": "8.590 G",
    "dual_mine": false,
    "invalid_shares": 0,
    "latency": 38,
    "pool_hashrate_10m": "343.6 M",
    "pool_hashrate_24h": "185.4 M",
    "pool_hashrate_4h": "200.6 M",
    "rejected_shares": 4,
    "url": "es.xxxx.com:1800",
    "use_ssl": false,
    "user": "xxxx.yyyy"
  },
  "version": "39.1"
}
```

I have try this command:

jq-win64.exe '.total_hashrate' json.txt

But it return a error message:

jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
'.total_hashrate'
jq: 1 compile error

And I have try this one:

jq-win64.exe .[].total_hashrate json.txt

It return the data with "" not I want:

"175.5 M"
jq: error (at json.txt:86): Cannot index number with string "total_hashrate"

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have find the way:

```
jq-win64.exe -r .miner.total_hashrate json.txt > total_hashrate.txt
```